# upload file using jquery in mvc razor

Tags: razor

I am new to MVC 3 Razor. How to upload file using Jquery.My code below mentioned

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
        <input type="Button" value="upload" />
    }
```

few restriction is below mentioned

- i can not define my action and controller within html.BeginForm(...)
- i can not use type="submit" of above upload button.

Now i hope you are clear when i click upload button jquery function will be call and from there my action should be call and in controller i want to implement my logic with uploaded file.

please let me know how to implement this.????any sample demo??

Answer (score 1):

It's easy

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
        <input type="Button" value="upload" onclick="upload()" />
    }

<script>
    function upload() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
            dataType: "multipart/form-data",
            data: $('#file'),
            cache: false
        });
    }
</script>
```